# How to create DDL trigger to all databases in SQL Server 2005 instance

Tags: t-sql, ddl-trigger

I am going to create a DDL trigger to all databases in SQL Server instance. I'd like to do it in one run instead of many runs for each database.

Below are the two T-SQL statements I need to execute:

```
-- Create table

use <dbname>
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.ChangeAttempt
(EventData xml NOT NULL,
AttemptDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
DBUser char(50) NOT NULL)
GO

-- Create DDL trigger 

use <dbname>
GO
CREATE TRIGGER db_trg_ObjectChanges
ON DATABASE
FOR ALTER_PROCEDURE, DROP_PROCEDURE,
 ALTER_INDEX, DROP_INDEX,
 ALTER_TABLE, DROP_TABLE, ALTER_TRIGGER, DROP_TRIGGER,
 ALTER_VIEW, DROP_VIEW, ALTER_SCHEMA, DROP_SCHEMA,
 ALTER_ROLE, DROP_ROLE, ALTER_USER, DROP_USER
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
INSERT dbo.ChangeAttempt
(EventData, DBUser)
VALUES (EVENTDATA(), USER)
GO
```

My question is: how can I programmaticaly create DDL trigger in one run?

Comment: I edited my question with a how to...

Comment: so how fast is it now? how can i get the right answer but no up votes?

Comment: it is fast. I'm able to do the creation to all SQL Servers in just a few hours. I'm sorry I don't know what you mean by "up votes". How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why do you need one run? this is the only way to do it.

```
Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
'CREATE TRIGGER' must be the first statement in a query batch.
```

run the output generated by this:

```
DECLARE @DatabaseName varchar(500)
DECLARE @Database_id  int
DECLARE @Query        varchar(8000)
DECLARE @CRLF         char(2)

SET @CRLF=CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
---MODIFY THIS TO INCLUDE THE DATABASES THAT YOU WANT TO WORk ON
---MODIFY THIS TO INCLUDE THE DATABASES THAT YOU WANT TO WORk ON
select @Database_id=MIN(database_id) from sys.databases where database_id IN (5,7,8,6)

WHILE @Database_id IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT @DatabaseName=name from sys.databases where database_id=@Database_id
    SET @Query='-- Create table'+@CRLF+@CRLF
                +'use '+@DatabaseName+@CRLF
                +' GO'+@CRLF
                +' CREATE TABLE dbo.ChangeAttempt'+@CRLF
                +' (EventData xml NOT NULL,'+@CRLF
                +' AttemptDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),'+@CRLF
                +' DBUser char(50) NOT NULL)'+@CRLF
                +'GO'+@CRLF+@CRLF
                +'-- Create DDL trigger '+@CRLF+@CRLF
                +'use '+@DatabaseName+@CRLF
                +'GO'+@CRLF
                +'CREATE TRIGGER db_trg_ObjectChanges'+@CRLF
                +'ON DATABASE'+@CRLF
                +'FOR ALTER_PROCEDURE, DROP_PROCEDURE,'+@CRLF
                +' ALTER_INDEX, DROP_INDEX,'+@CRLF
                +' ALTER_TABLE, DROP_TABLE, ALTER_TRIGGER, DROP_TRIGGER,'+@CRLF
                +' ALTER_VIEW, DROP_VIEW, ALTER_SCHEMA, DROP_SCHEMA,'+@CRLF
                +' ALTER_ROLE, DROP_ROLE, ALTER_USER, DROP_USER'+@CRLF
                +'AS'+@CRLF
                +'SET NOCOUNT ON'+@CRLF
                +'INSERT dbo.ChangeAttempt'+@CRLF
                +'(EventData, DBUser)'+@CRLF
                +'VALUES (EVENTDATA(), USER)'+@CRLF
                +'GO'+@CRLF
    PRINT @Query
    ---MODIFY THIS TO INCLUDE THE DATABASES THAT YOU WANT TO WORk ON
    ---MODIFY THIS TO INCLUDE THE DATABASES THAT YOU WANT TO WORk ON
    select @Database_id=MIN(database_id) from sys.databases WHERE database_id IN (5,7,8,6) AND database_id>@Database_id
END
```

**EDIT**
to determine what databases to generate scripts for do the following:

- run this query:

  select database_id,name  from sys.databases
- find all of the databases you want to run the scripts for
- change my above script *in two places* (before loop & at bottom in loop) so all of the database_id that you want are in the following code section:

  WHERE database_id IN (AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD,....)

Comment: I forgot to mention, I'd like to implement this kind of auditing in SQL Server 2000. What are the options I can try to do this?

Comment: When I tried it in some servers, the output lacks some of the databases as I can by querying sys.databases. Any opinion why?

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot for further explanations.

Answer (score 0):

You could use sp_MSforeachdb.

Something like this

```
sp_MSforeachdb
'
    CREATE TABLE ?.dbo.ChangeAttempt
        etc. etc. etc.
'
sp_MSforeachdb
'
    CREATE TRIGGER ?.dbo.db_trg_ObjectChanges
        etc. etc. etc.
'
```

I haven't tested this, in theory I'd expect it to work though. You want to make sure you exclude the system databases though.