# Trigger on database not table only

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

When we insert or update data in a table, at time I want the primary key and table name to be inserted in another table.
I need this to reconcile at the end of day,  all tables that are updated today.

Please suggest. Thank you.

Comment: You need one trigger per table.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946118/how-to-create-ddl-trigger-to-all-databases-in-sql-server-2005-instance

Comment: @Meherzad  - completely off-topic

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at CDC - [Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Or Paul Nielsen's [AutoAudit](https://autoaudit.codeplex.com/).

Comment: thank you. but i am not getting the full solution from would you like to provide me any other helping links

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.objects
WHERE DATEDIFF(D,modify_date, GETDATE()) < 1
```

By using this query you can able to get all the modification of your database. In place of 1 you can able to give no of days you want to see the change.

Comment: not sure how reliable that is....

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out something like this...I hope it answers your question.

1. Create a few test tables for demonstration
2. Create the SQL to create triggers on all the tables
3. Simple insert statements.

> ```
>    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[log_table](
>           [table_name] [varchar](1000) NULL,
>           [column_name] [varchar](1000) NULL,
>           [column_value] [varchar](1000) NULL,
>           [datetime] [datetime] NULL
>         ) 
>         GO
> ```

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Animals](
        [AnimalID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [AnimalName] [varchar](50) NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Animals] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    ([AnimalID] ASC)
    )

    GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Countries](
        [CountryID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
        [CountryName] [varchar](50) NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Countries] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    ([CountryID] ASC))
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Countries] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Countries_countryID]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [CountryID]
    GO
```

> ```
>     SELECT 
>   ' IF OBJECT_ID ('+ CHAR(39) + SCHEMA_NAME(tbl.SCHEMA_ID) + '.trg_' + tbl.name + CHAR(39) + ',''TR'') IS NOT NULL ' + 
>   ' DROP TRIGGER ' + SCHEMA_NAME(tbl.SCHEMA_ID) + '.trg_'+ tbl.name + ';' + 
>   ' EXEC (' + CHAR(39) +
>   ' CREATE TRIGGER ' + SCHEMA_NAME(tbl.SCHEMA_ID) + '.trg_'+ tbl.name + 
>   ' ON '+ SCHEMA_NAME(tbl.SCHEMA_ID) + '.' + tbl.name + ' FOR INSERT,UPDATE AS ' + 
>   ' DECLARE @newval varchar(1000) ' + 
>   ' SELECT @newval ='+ COL_NAME(tbl.object_id, ic.column_id) + ' FROM INSERTED' + 
>   ' INSERT INTO log_table(table_name,column_name,column_value,datetime) VALUES('+ 
>   CHAR(39)+ CHAR(39) + SCHEMA_NAME(tbl.SCHEMA_ID)  +'.'+  tbl.name + CHAR(39)+ CHAR(39) + ' ,'+ 
>   CHAR(39)+ CHAR(39) + COL_NAME(tbl.object_id, ic.column_id) + CHAR(39)+ CHAR(39) + ' ,'+     
>   '@newval,getdate()'+ ')' + CHAR(39)+ ')'
> FROM
>   sys.tables AS tbl
>   INNER JOIN  sys.key_constraints AS kc ON kc.parent_object_id = tbl.object_id
>   INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS i  ON kc.unique_index_id = i.index_id  AND kc.parent_object_id = i.object_id
>   INNER JOIN sys.index_columns AS ic  ON i.object_id = ic.object_id  AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
> WHERE  tbl.type = 'U'  AND ic.is_included_column = 0 and tbl.name NOT IN ('sysdiagrams','log_table')
> ORDER BY  tbl.object_id,  ic.key_ordinal;
> ```

Now insert into our tables

> ```
> INSERT INTO Countries(CountryName) VALUES('South Africa')
> INSERT INTO Countries(CountryName) VALUES('USA')
> INSERT INTO Countries(CountryName) VALUES('Brazil')
> INSERT INTO Countries(CountryName) VALUES('Zimbabwe')
> INSERT INTO Countries(CountryName) VALUES('Africa is not a country')
>
>
> INSERT INTO Animals(AnimalName) VALUES ('Lion')
> INSERT INTO Animals(AnimalName) VALUES ('African Elephant')
> INSERT INTO Animals(AnimalName) VALUES ('Rhinoceros')
> INSERT INTO Animals(AnimalName) VALUES ('Leopard')
> INSERT INTO Animals(AnimalName) VALUES ('Cape Buffalo')
> ```

Comment: As far as I am concerned, this question is clear enough. Manoj needs to keep track of tables that are updated on a daily basis, and also be able to see the value of the primary key for the inserted/updated record. That's how I understood it.